# My anonymous inner class mouse adapter is doing things on its own

Tags: java, repeat, mouselistener, anonymous-inner-class

This is not the first time where a *part* of my code is executed on its own, and I can't understand why. I've run the debugger, and then it seems to go back to a random line of code.

In this situation, it finishes all the code in the `MouseAdapter`, but then it goes right back to the `if(boundaryIndex==1)...`—not even `if(me.getSource()==backBtn)`—and it executes the code below repeatedly until `boundaryIndex` is equal to `1`, and *then* the code ends.

```
MouseAdapter ma = 
  new MouseAdapter()
  {
```

...

```
     public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me)
     {
```

...

```
if(me.getSource()==backBtn) // this statement is called repeatedly.
{
   if(boundaryIndex==1)
   {
      backBtn.setIcon(backDisabled);
      for(MouseListener l : backBtn.getMouseListeners())
          backBtn.removeMouseListener(l);
   }
   boundaryIndex--;
   restoreBackground();
   try{
      for (int b : map.territories.get(boundaryIndex).getBorders())
          img.getGraphics().drawImage(
              blueIco,
              map.territories.get(b).getPoint().x - blueIco.getWidth() / 2,
              map.territories.get(b).getPoint().y - blueIco.getHeight() / 2,
              null);
   } catch(Exception e) {}
   img.getGraphics().drawImage(
       redIco,
       map.territories.get(boundaryIndex).getPoint().x - redIco.getWidth() / 2,
       map.territories.get(boundaryIndex).getPoint().y - redIco.getHeight() / 2,
       null);
   background.repaint();
}
```

...

```
    }
};
```

I wish I could explain this better, but I just don't understand it. It defies everything I know about Java. There are no loops, it really, actually, seriously, jumps to a line of code. It JUMPS to it. It starts off INSIDE of the if-statement, and the if-statement isn't even checked after the first run-through. It literally starts right in the middle of it.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't think this is answerable because we can't see what is surrounding the code.  What is is part of?  I don't think we have enough context.  (For one thing, you're referring to an anonymous inner class, but I don't see one in your code.)

Comment: Atleast add the full `MouseAdapter` source. We don't event know whether given code is executed in a loop. Also you may want to mention how the mouse listeners are being added to the `backBtn` and explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: @user3376587 How many mouse listeners added to the backBtn? Are all of them of same type? When do you add the listener?

Comment: I am embarrassed to say I was adding mouselisteners in a for loop, and it turned out that it had more than 1, so it was calling the code repeatedly. Problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

I was adding mouse listeners in a for loop. It turned out that the component was given the same mouse listener multiple times. Problem solved.